# Is there a way to make a html list behave like this

Tags: html, css, list

I'm creating a drag and drop seat plan. I have been doing all sorts of way to manipulate the list to look like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/41Td4.png]

it currently look like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/41Tcy.png]

How can I reverse it? i want the teacher to feel that he's just facing the class. is this possible? Thank you in advance!

styles.css

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;

}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:500px;
}
#contentLeft li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    background-color:#2a70db;
    border: #CCCCCC solid 1px;
    color:#fff;
    float:right;
    margin: 3px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Add a break after the second li element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css selectors. In your case, the 3'rd element should be on a new line so you can clear floats with him.

The code will be like this:

```
li:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}
```